# Custom Tumblr subdomain redirects to website instead of showing Tumblr content

Tags: subdomain, tumblr

I am trying to create subdomain (`tumblr.example.com`) so that it shows up as the URL for Tumblr. I have created the CName records using `domains.tumblr.com` as the alias just like all the help/forum pages say.

I tested it under the settings in Tumblr. I have waited over night,  and it still just redirects back to my website. Thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: When you say "still just redirects back to my website" are you saying that is what it used to do before?   If so, it sounds like DNS just hasn't propagated yet.  Depending on your time to live (TTL) settings that could take up to 3 days.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is redirecting to your main site as opposed to your non-custom Tumblr URL, right?